# Is there function available in Numpy / Python, which provide output of ALL SATISFIED CONDITIONS (not 1st satisfied condition as given by np.select)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I am new to Python / Numpy. Currently, I am working on code to evaluate optimum condition / conditions from condition list (multiple conditions given in condition list).

I am aware of Numpy Select function, which return an array drawn from elements in choicelist, depending on conditions.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

Syntax : numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default = 0)

Parameters :

condlist : [list of bool ndarrays] It determine from which array in choicelist the output elements are taken. When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used.
choicelist : [list of ndarrays] The list of arrays from which the output elements are taken. It has to be of the same length as condlist.
default : [scalar, optional] The element inserted in output when all conditions evaluate to False.

Return : [ndarray] An array drawn from elements in choicelist, depending on conditions.

By using Numpy Select function, when multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used.

**Problem:**

Is there a function available in Numpy / Python, which provide output of **ALL SATISFIED CONDITIONS** (NOT first satisfied condition as provided by Numpy Select function) from condlist?

If such function is not available, can someone help to build such function?

**Example:**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 10, 20, 20], "B": [10, 0, 10, 0]})

condlist = [(df.A + df.B == 20), (df.A == 10) & (df.B == 0), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 10), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 0)]

choicelist = [(df.A + df.B), 'No', 'Hi', 'YES']

calculate = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

df['RESULT'] = pd.Series(calculate, index=df.index)

df
```

**Output:**

|  | A | B | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | No |
| 2 | 20 | 10 | Hi |
| 3 | 20 | 0 | 20 # *Desire Output:* ***20, YES*** |

Last raw, desire RESULT output should be **20, YES** (as condition # 4 (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 0) also TRUE).

**Reference:** Numpy Select source code hyperlink is as below. Refer to Line 626 to Line 719 for detail.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L626-L719

I appreciate your consideration and support.

Warm regards,

Keyush

Comment: What will this output look like?  Multiple arrays?  Ragged arrays?  `np.select` returns one array with values drawn from the choices.  When you want a result that can vary in size across dimensions, it is highly unlikely that you'll find a `numpy` function.  The fast compiled code is designed around the concept of regular multidimensional arrays - as in put and output.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 10, 20, 20], "B": [10, 0, 10, 0]})

result = np.select([(df.A + df.B == 20), (df.A == 10) & (df.B == 0), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 10), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 0)], [(df.A + df.B), 'No', 'No', 'YES'])

df['RESULT'] = pd.Series(result, index=df.index)

df

Output:


Last raw, RESULT output should be 20, YES (as condition # 4 (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 0) also TRUE).

Is there a function available in Numpy / Python, which provide output of ALL SATISFIED CONDITIONS from condlist?

If such function is not available, can you help to build such function?

Comment: If this is a `pandas` question, add the right tag.  And put code like this in the question.  Formatting is lost in comments.

Comment: I realize formatting issue. Due to that, I just updated my original question and add example. My apology as I am new to this webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is as below with help from one of the experts.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 10, 20, 20], "B": [10, 0, 10, 0]})

condlist = [(df.A + df.B == 20), (df.A == 10) & (df.B == 0), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 10), (df.A == 20) & (df.B == 0)]

condarray = np.array(condlist) # bool representation where each row is a condition and each column is a row of the df

cond_true = [np.where(i)[0] for i in condarray.T]

df['result']= cond_true
```

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
import numpy as np
def myselect(A, B):
    conditions = [lambda x,y: x == y,
                  lambda x,y: (x ==20) & (y == 20),
                  lambda x,y: x + y == 20,
                  ...
                 ]
    # These are the desired output for each satisfied condition
    result_values = ['0isTrue', '1isTrue' ...]
    assert len(conditions) == len(result_values)
    assert len(A) == len(B)
    C = [] * len(A)
    for i in range(len(conditions)):
        r = conditions[i](x, y)
        for j, v in enumerate(r):
            if v:
                C[j].append(result_values[i])
    return C

# Generate a bunch of values to test with
top = <top-value-to-generate>
elements = <number-of-elements-to-test>
rng = np.random.default_rng()
A = rng.integers(0, top, elements)
B = rng.integers(0, top, elements)
result = myselect(A, B)
```

Notes:

- The output will be "ragged" (different number of 2nd dimension values) so it it not suitable to be a numpy array and therefore not suitable to be inside NumPy. Also your example shows mixed `str` and `int` in the `result_values`, which is also not really NumPy friendly. So I used a list-of-lists for C.
- Perhaps there is a way to do this with less looping. But as always in writing code: first make it correct, then make it fast.
- The lambdas (you could use functions instead) are evaluated one-at-a-time. `np.select` seems to take a pre-evaluated condition list. So this solution might use less memory when `elements` is very large.
- You could `pass conditions` and `result_values` into `myselect`